# Computer doesn't wake from sleep Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, suspend, dell

I have two Dell computers, both running Ubuntu 20.04, that are both not waking from sleep when I try using the keyboard or the mouse. It seems like this might have started happening with both of them after certain updates installed, but I'm not certain. I've run diagnostics on both machines to confirm that this is not a Dell hardware issue, and deep sleep mode is deactivated.